# how to maintain confidentiality of an organization doing a confidential search

Tags: interviewing

is there a generic form that can be used by an organization that is doing a confidential search that restricts candidates from disclosing the name of the organization they are interviewing with?

Comment: Why would I sign such a form?

Comment: @LarsFriedrich If you don't sign it, you don't get interviewed

Comment: @HLGEM I was aware of the consequences. While there are good reasons for an employee to do a confidential search, there are not many for a company - f.e. to prepare the sudden dismissal of another employee. But then I would work for a company which doesn't mind to do that which means I might suffer the same fate. Would I want to work for such a company in the first place?

Comment: @LarsFriedrich Not many for a company? Many companies don't want to expose the inner workings. What if they want to go a new direction and don't want the competition to know?

Comment: @Frisbee What advantage will that be if I can talk about the company I work for on working day #1, when the company doesn't have made any progress in the new direction? Unless I'm also not allowed to mention the name of the company I work for until the product is released, it serves only an imaginary purpose. I do get an NDA regarding what you have to do, but  regarding the name of the company? Seriously, would you work for a company where you couldn't even tell this your wife/husband? Unless it's a top secret government agency, I wouldn't.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich Imaginary?  What?  You don't know how much progress they have or have not made.  Why they want a confidential search is not the question.   The question is disclose the name they are interviewing with.   INTERVIEW not work.  Nothing about that question is not disclose the name of the company after you take the job.  Don't work them if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

No outside of special cases such as those covered by the official secrets Act  (our your country's equivalent) there is no legal way to restrict candidates from disclosing this.

Answer (score 1):

It is a confidentiality agreement and they are enforceable.

This is probably better on law.stackexchange.com

The agreement would prohibit them from disclosing anything said or shared at the interview but I don't think you can prohibit them from disclosing they signed a confidentiality agreement with your company.

Typically you would go thru a recruiting agency for this type of confidential search.  You could even have an anonymous phone interview.  At some point you have to disclose the name of the company.

Comment: Are they actually enforceable though - you might be able to enforce it but I doubt many courts would impose any serious penalty in fact they might award 1 penny damages.

Comment: @Pepone IANAL.  Courts can award a range of damages.  What do you think the damage would be for disclosing the recipe to Coke?

Comment: that's not the Q asked  its the name of the company being disclosed not stealing trade secrets

Comment: @Pepone I know that is not the question.  I clearly state a confidentiality  agreement probably could not be used to restrict disclosing the name of the company.  So clearly my response was in terms of damages in general.  Your comment is "they".

Comment: SE doesn't allow editing I thought my point was clear from context when I went back to edit it I could not

Comment: @Pepone And SE does not allow me to take back an up vote